# Shiro/Spring MVC Redirect to original/requested page upon successful login

Tags: spring-mvc, shiro

How to achieve below scenario in a Spring MVC application with Shiro security:

> If the user not authenticated and requesting for a page, Shiro should
>   redirect to the login page. The user logs in successfully and Shiro
>   redirects to the previously requested page instead of the `successUrl`
>   URL

The login part is working alright in my application. Below is a snippet from my existing code

```
<!-- Shiro filter -->
    <bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
        <property name="loginUrl" value="/login" />
        <property name="successUrl" value="/dashboard" />
        <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/error" />
        <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
            <value> 
                <!-- !!! Order matters !!! -->
                /authenticate = anon
                /login = anon
                /logout = anon
                /error = anon
                /static/** = anon
                /** = authc
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

in the LoginController:

```
public String doLogin(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(required = true) String username,
        @RequestParam(required = true) String password,
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean rememberMe,
        Model model) {
    Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

    ...

    if (currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
        String fallbackUrl = "redirect:/";
        try {
            // redirect to previously requested page
            WebUtils.redirectToSavedRequest(request, response, fallbackUrl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            return fallbackUrl;
        }
        // return null to prevent spring render another page
        return null;
    } else {
        session.setAttribute("loginFailCount", ++loginFailCount);
    }
    return "login";
}
```